Ionic angular multiple modal open close problem
There are three modal close itself and then open another modal from the inside of the modal
This is the structure for ion modal
<ion-modal id="last-modal" #modal_s [backdropDismiss]="false">
        <ng-template>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <ion-item lines="none" class="offer-item ion-no-padding">
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label class="offer-title">{{offer.title[lg]}}</ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-icon
                (click)="closelastModal('last-modal');"
                style="color: var(--ion-color-modal-exp)"
                size="small"
                name="close-outline"
              ></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <div
              style="
                display: flex;
                background-color: var(--ion-color-modal-img-background);
                border-radius: 16px;
                margin-left: 12px;
                margin-right: 12px;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 24px;
              "
            >
              <ion-img
                [src]="offer.img == null || offer.img.length === 0 
           ? 'assets/images/cofee_cup.png' 
            : offer.img"
                alt="Coffee Cup"
                class="custom-card-img"
              />
            </div>

            <p
              style="
                margin-left: 12px;
                margin-right: 12px;
                margin-top: 8px;
                color: var(--ion-color-modal-description);
              "
            >
              {{offer.text[lg]}}
            </p>
            <p class="exp-date">
              {{ "OFFERS.EXPIRY" | translate }} {{offer.expirationDate | date :
              "MMM dd, HH:mm"}}
            </p>
            <ion-button
              expand="block"
              class="custom-button"
              (click)="closelastModal('last-modal');modalService.openOfferActionModal($event, offer, 'store')"
            >
              <!-- (click)="closeModal();modalService.openOfferActionModal($event, offer, 'store')" -->
              {{ "OFFERS.REDEEM" | translate }}
              <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ion-modal>
and then 
 openAnotherModal(nextModalId: string) {
    const modalElement = document.getElementById(nextModalId);
    modalElement?.setAttribute('is-open', 'true'); // Open the next modal
  }

  closeAnotherModal(modalId: string) {
    const modalElement = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modalElement?.setAttribute('is-open', 'false'); // Close the modal
  }

here is three modal open one by another from the button of the modal itself and now I want to close the itself modal using close button and then use another button which close the self modal and open the next modal.
My problem is by using this system close and open functionality when call simultaneously then it will work but for the close button functionality not work but it work if I use modal_s.dismiss() but if once call this then next openModal will not work what should be the solution am very new in ionic platform, please help

To implement a system where one modal closes itself and then opens another, while ensuring the proper behaviour of modal dismissal and reopening, follow these steps:
Problem Breakdown

Ionic Modal Behavior: When using modal.dismiss(), the modal is destroyed, making it unavailable for reopening unless it's recreated.

Simultaneous Close and Open: The sequence might be mishandled, leading to conflicts in modal lifecycle events.


Suggested Solution:
Use the Ionic Modal Controller's API effectively to manage the modal lifecycle. Avoid dirfectly manipulating DOM elements like setAttribute.
Template Code
    <ion-modal id="last-modal" [is-open]="isLastModalOpen" [backdropDismiss]="false">
  <ng-template>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ion-item lines="none" class="offer-item ion-no-padding">
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label class="offer-title">{{ offer.title[lg] }}</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-icon
          (click)="closeModal('last-modal')"
          style="color: var(--ion-color-modal-exp)"
          size="small"
          name="close-outline"
        ></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <div
        style="
          display: flex;
          background-color: var(--ion-color-modal-img-background);
          border-radius: 16px;
          margin-left: 12px;
          margin-right: 12px;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          padding: 24px;
        "
      >
        <ion-img
          [src]="offer.img == null || offer.img.length === 0 ? 'assets/images/cofee_cup.png' : offer.img"
          alt="Coffee Cup"
          class="custom-card-img"
        />
      </div>
      <p
        style="
          margin-left: 12px;
          margin-right: 12px;
          margin-top: 8px;
          color: var(--ion-color-modal-description);
        "
      >
        {{ offer.text[lg] }}
      </p>
      <p class="exp-date">
        {{ "OFFERS.EXPIRY" | translate }} {{ offer.expirationDate | date: "MMM dd, HH:mm" }}
      </p>
      <ion-button
        expand="block"
        class="custom-button"
        (click)="closeAndOpenNextModal('last-modal', 'next-modal-id')"
      >
        {{ "OFFERS.REDEEM" | translate }}
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>

Component Logic
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-example',
  templateUrl: './modal-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-example.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalExampleComponent {
  isLastModalOpen = false;

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {}

  // Open a modal
  async openModal(modalId: string) {
    const modalElement = document.getElementById(modalId);
    if (modalElement) {
      this.isLastModalOpen = true; // Update state
    }
  }

  // Close the current modal
  async closeModal(modalId: string) {
    const modalElement = await this.modalController.getTop();
    if (modalElement) {
      await modalElement.dismiss();
      this.isLastModalOpen = false; // Update state
    }
  }

  // Close the current modal and open another
  async closeAndOpenNextModal(currentModalId: string, nextModalId: string) {
    await this.closeModal(currentModalId); // Close the current modal
    this.openModal(nextModalId); // Open the next modal
  }
}

Explanation:

[is-open] Attribute Binding: Use Angular's property binding to toggle modal visibility instead of manipulation DOM attributes.

Modal Dismissal: Use the Ionic's ModalController's dimiss method to ensure the modal lifecycle is properly managed.

Sequential Close and Open: Ensure the current modal is fully dismissed(await) before opening the next modal to avoid lifecycle conflicts.


